# Help with simple beginner circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, esp8266

I hope someone can help me with a circuit idea I have. I want to build a door sensor with a reed switch and an ESP8266. I want to keep it low power. When the reed switch closes the circuit it should provide power to the ESP 8266 while charging a capacitor. When the door shuts the capacitor will be charged and will dissipate its energy to the ESP8266 keeping it on a little longer to finish sending a message to my Raspberry Pi that the door was opened.

I am assuming this is a fairly basic circuit but I am a beginner and could not really find anything online about doing this. Could someone help with the basic design and the size of capacitor I will need to store enough power to keep the ESP 8266 on for the quarter of a second or so?

Comment: why don't you send the message when the door is first opened?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a battery and having the ESP8266 shut down when it's finished transmitting. Reed switches are not a good way to switch a lot of current (they tend to enjoy welding) and the required capacitor would be large (eg. a 1V drop at 250mA requires 250,000uF). And 1V drop means an additional regulator (eg. 5V to 3.3V).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this circuit is that the ESP8266 needs a little more time to connect to the WiFi when it starts up.

You could use the ESP8266 DeepSleep library. With this library you can put the MCU into a sleep mode where the power consumption drops to about 20 µA. With the reed switch, you could then give the wake-up signal to the MCU.

Comment: He only has to take in mind the important role of the LDO, I guess he will not make his own board.. something like the ESP32 Firebeetle would be my suggestion. Otherwise it will never get these low values.